# how to save to a new csv file every time it goes through the loop per page

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime

# launch WMS
url = "https://inserturlhere.com/solution/login.htm"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)

#Login start
username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("xxx")

password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("xxx")

driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
#login end


# set variables
pageSize = 200
pageNo = 0
currentView = 33362
entityName = "Item"
now = datetime.now()

def get_filename_datetime():
    return str(entityName) + "-" + str(now.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")) +".csv"

for pageNo in range(10):
    url2 = "https://inserturlhere.com/solution/entitylist.htm?entityName=Item&tabName=Item&pageNo={pageNo}&pageSize={pageSize}&currentViewId={currentView}".format(pageNo=pageNo, pageSize=pageSize, currentView=currentView)
    # open shipments page
    driver.get(url2)
    html = driver.page_source
    dfs = pd.read_html(html, attrs={"class":"roundedTable"}, header=5)
    for df in dfs:
        df.dropna(how="all", axis="columns", inplace=True)
        df.drop({"No", "Process Action"}, axis="columns", inplace=True)
        df.dropna(how='all', axis=0, inplace=True)
        df.append(dfs)
        df.to_csv(get_filename_datetime(), index=False)
```

hey guys. how can i modify the code above to save a new csv every time it loops per page? right now, it's only saving a single file that contains the last page from the scrape.

Let me know if additional data is needed! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tested `get_filename_datetime` does it work? `for df in dfs:` you are iterating over something then - `df.append(dfs)` appending the *iterable* to the item - that seems kinda wierd. Was that intentional? Making a **minimal** [mcve] for us might help you figure it out. walking through your code with pencil and paper is often instructive. - [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: When you printed `get_filename_datetime()` just before the `to_csv` call did you get what you expected?

Comment: hi wwii, yes the get_filename_datetime is working and i got what i expected as far as filename goes. However, it's only saving the last page that i looped into the csv file. it's not really appending the results per page to my df.

As you pointed out, I may be doing the Append completely incorrectly. 
If i can have the results into one dataframe, that would be ideal than having to get a single csv file per page. That is my goal actually but i dont know how to do that.

Please let me know! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the filename never changes, so the loop constantly overwrites it. There is only 1 value for now, it doesn't change as time passes.

```
entityName = "Item"
now = datetime.now()

def get_filename_datetime():
    return str(entityName) + "-" + str(now.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")) +".csv"
```

As an aside, the loop also seems to have an error, as noted by wwii, in that you are appending a list of dataframes (dfs) to an individual dataframe. If your intention is to go through all of the HTML tables on the page, make some modifications, and then combine them, you should append the modified df to a new list and then concatenate and save it.

```
modified_dfs = []
for df in pd.read_html(html, attrs={"class":"roundedTable"}, header=5):
    df = df.dropna(how="all", axis="columns")
    df = df.drop({"No", "Process Action"}, axis="columns")
    df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
    modified_dfs.append(df)
pd.concat(modified_dfs).to_csv('unique_filename', index=False)
```

Comment: modified my code and works now!
also. thanks for giving me the solution regarding the append/concat! works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `pageNo` as a unique number to add to the filename:

```py
df.to_csv(f'{get_filename_datetime()}_{pageNo}', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks! I modified a bit and it is now saving per page result!


```df.to_csv(get_filename_datetime()+ "_" + str({pageNo})```

Comment: Cool! If you accept my answer we can close the question :-)

Comment: I am using f-strings there, but they're new since Python 3.6: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: Hi, any idea how i can combine all results into one dataframe then create only a single CSV file from it?

Comment: Yes but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried it, but might be your dfs for loop runs under second. Try adding 1 second delay in your loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime
import time

# launch WMS
url = "https://inserturlhere.com/solution/login.htm"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)

#Login start
username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("xxx")

password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("xxx")

driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
#login end


# set variables
pageSize = 200
pageNo = 0
currentView = 33362
entityName = "Item"
now = datetime.now()

def get_filename_datetime():
    return str(entityName) + "-" + str(now.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")) +".csv"

for pageNo in range(10):
    url2 = "https://inserturlhere.com/solution/entitylist.htm?entityName=Item&tabName=Item&pageNo={pageNo}&pageSize={pageSize}&currentViewId={currentView}".format(pageNo=pageNo, pageSize=pageSize, currentView=currentView)
    # open shipments page
    driver.get(url2)
    html = driver.page_source
    dfs = pd.read_html(html, attrs={"class":"roundedTable"}, header=5)
    for df in dfs:
        df.dropna(how="all", axis="columns", inplace=True)
        df.drop({"No", "Process Action"}, axis="columns", inplace=True)
        df.dropna(how='all', axis=0, inplace=True)
        df.append(dfs)
        df.to_csv(get_filename_datetime(), index=False)
        time.sleep(1)
```